# Can I make baccala (Italian salted cod) at home relatively easily?

Tags: fish, italian-cuisine, cod

I would like to make some Italian baccalà dishes. However, I am unable to get my hands on baccalà. Also I have a box of frozen cod fillets sitting in the freezer that I don't want to waste. Can I make baccalà at home? Any easy way to do so? All I can find on Google with "baccala" are recipes that call for baccala, not how to make this important ingredient.

Comment: There are many recipes on the internet to make your own salted cod; have you look at them ?

Comment: @Max Maybe I wasn't thorough enough? My searches all included the keyword "baccala". I went five pages without seeing one Google hit about making baccala. Almost every hit was about _using_ it. I wanted to find how to make baccala specifically, because I needed it for Italian recipes. I wasn't sure if regular salted cod was made the same way because, well, I didn't know how to make baccala.

Comment: I googled "dry your own cod"

Comment: @Max Darn it. I should have known people salt their cod the same anywhere in the world. :P Seriously though, I honestly and reasonably thought there would be differences in making salted cod. Japanese, Korean, Greek salted fish roes are all made quite differently. Not to mention cured meats or cheeses around the world. So it wouldn't be a stretch to believe baccala was unique in its own right, would it?

Comment: Italian baccala and Spanish baccala are often made from cod that's been imported from colder waters (like Ireland, Norway or Finland).  So you should search for one of those countries for how to actually salt the cod : https://cod.fromnorway.com/norwegian-cod/salted-cod/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  Instructions from the book *[The Cuisines of Spain](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/198405/the-cuisines-of-spain-by-teresa-barrenechea/)*:

1. Get several cod filets, preferably skin-on
2. Cover the bottom of a large non-reactive pan or dish with coarse salt (such as kosher salt)
3. Put the filets side-by-side on the salt.
4. Cover them with coarse salt.  They should be completely covered, with no fish showing.
5. Place the pan, uncovered, in the refrigerator for 48 hours.
6. Every 12 hours, pour off any accumulated liquids.  This will wash away some of the salt, so add salt as needed to re-cover the fish.
7. Lift the fish out of the salt and wipe it down with damp towels to remove the outer salt.
8. Use or freeze within a couple of weeks.